# Is killing a robber by shooting first considered murder?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, murder, rodef

Apologies if this has already been answered :

If someone comes up to you on the street waving a gun and demanding your money and you immediately draw your concealed weapon and shoot and kill them, is that considered murder or valid self defense? Is it like when a thief enters your house in the middle of the night, or different because it happened on public property? Could you claim the robber was a rodef because as soon as he pointed a gun at you he could have shot you at any point, and so your life was in danger?

Comment: No. Not murder. Self defense is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud says: lf someone comes to kill you, kill him first (if that is the only way to stop him).  Pointing a gun at you can only be interpreted as a threat to kill you.  So you would be justified in taking his life first.

Comment: It's very likely they don't really want to kill you but just want your valuables. So I don't know if that fits the "If someone comes to kill you" condition.

Comment: You can't read his mind, so you must assume he is prepared to kill you.

Comment: "Prepared to" doesn't mean "wants to" or "will". Will post an answer shortly.

Comment: @stilez doesn’t matter what he intends to do. If someone points a gun to your face it is your duty to shoot till dead. If someone points a gun to your face they are going to kill you. If you do not shoot first that means you don’t value your life at all.

Comment: @TurkHill - I hope you never, ever, ever, have to account for those words to your creator, who valued life as much as his commandments show.  "Your duty to shoot till dead"....... I am sad for you, my fellow human.

Comment: @Stilez On the contrary, I hope your never in a situation where you have to defend yourself or your family. I will tell you right now. If someone points a gun at me they're dead. And rightfully so. If you didn't want to die you should had never pointed a gun at me. I am sad that you don't seemingly value your life as much as a miserable criminal. I hope if your ever in a dangerous situation--G-d forbid!--you will choose the right thing and defend yourself.

Comment: No. The difference is, if I ever have a gun pointed at me, I will not take that as a free pass to kill. I'll do what I can to avoid any lives being lost, mine or others, or minimise the risk of it, and not assume mine means more than anyone else's. After all, did judges in ancient times not fast, and rent their clothes, on the day of a death sentence? Or does the Talmud say they should go and high five, celebrate taking "miserable criminals" off the streets and party on down? I think you know which. That's judges. That's how life's value is seen. Ease with killing passing as self defence, no

Comment: "Duty" to shoot "till dead". Ugh. You do realise any court would classify that as murder 1, don't you? And that's before your creator chips in with His view. You know, the bit that says do not murder?

Answer (score -2):

The Talmud says ([Sanhedrin 74a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.74a.11)):

> The ruling of the mishna is stated with regard to a young woman who was raped in a case where one was able to save her by injuring the pursuer in one of his limbs, so that it was not necessary to kill him in order to achieve her rescue, and it is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yonatan ben Shaul. As it is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Yonatan ben Shaul says: If a pursuer was pursuing another to kill him, and one was able to save the pursued party without killing the pursuer, but instead by injuring him in one of his limbs, but he did not save him in this manner and rather chose to kill him, he is executed on his account as a murderer.

So even killing a certain perpetrator of a very serious crime (rape), who **certainly committed** the crime, when that killing was avoidable, makes one a murderer. Therefore in the context of the question here, where one kills someone who has **not even committed** the very serious crime (murder), **and apparently does not wish to do** (it appears they want a threat not to actually kill), to kill them when avoidable, is surely murder.

Since their action appears to be avoidable by handing over the wallet, shooting them instead would apparently be murder.

And again (same source):

> From where do we derive this halakha with regard to a murderer himself, that one must allow himself to be killed rather than commit murder? The Gemara answers: It is based on logical reasoning that one life is not preferable to another, and therefore there is no need for a verse to teach this halakha. The Gemara relates an incident to demonstrate this: As when a certain person came before Rabba and said to him: The lord of my place, a local official, said to me: Go kill so-and-so, and if not I will kill you, what shall I do? Rabba said to him: It is preferable that he should kill you and you should not kill. Who is to say that your blood is redder than his, that your life is worth more than the one he wants you to kill? Perhaps that man’s blood is redder. This logical reasoning is the basis for the halakha that one may not save his own life by killing another.

So a person is not permitted to **certainly** save their own life (which will **certainly** be ended in an unlawful manner) by committing a killing themself. Therefore it is hard to see how a person could be permitted to only **potentially** save their own life (which is only **maybe** going to be ended in an unlawful manner) by committing a killing themself.

Comment: Your second source isn't a good example for this question. The case in that Gemara is talking about killing an unrelated third party, the question is asking about killing the potential murderer.

Comment: Thanks. Im using it to emphasise a related point that arises in both that and the OP question, though. Namely, that if killing another person to (**absolutely certainly**) save a life, is prohibited, then so much more so, must be killing someone to merely **perhaps** save a life. And yet, **even more so again**, when the situation also strongly suggests the weapon is a threat and their goal is a piece of property (money) and not even to kill, despite the presence of the weapon.

Comment: Based on your logic, it would never be allowed to kill in self defense.

Comment: Not so. There is a difference. Here, you would be killing to defend **property** not life. The robber might shoot you, it's true. He has a gun waving. And what is he doing with it? Demanding mere property. So as in those 2 quoted sections, we cannot just kill because of mere fear without actual necessity (i.e. the fear that he might use the gun a different way even though he has not indicated any such intention at all). This may not be a modern mundane view but does stem directly from Talmud. Life - even that of a robber - is too precious to kill just because of fear of a maybe.

Comment: You are, in effect, asking the OP to kill a third party, ostensibly to prevent a murder being committed by a third party. That's quote #2, dont kill one life to save another, even your own. And if you say he has a gun.... well, yes but at this point shows no indication of wishing to kill with it, so it's even worse, you would have the OP kill a person, to prevent some person taking some mere money (not even killing anyone), which despite your fears and the presence of a waved gun, is jn fact all that is actually threatened at this time.

Comment: We have a would-be assailant and a would-be victim. What third party is being killed when the would-be victim kills the the would-be assailant? For the record, I am making no comment on whether your conclusion that the would-be victim cannot kill the would-be assailant is correct or not. It could very well be true that the would-be victim cannot use lethal force to defend himself. I am just saying that the Gemara you are quoting is not a valid parallel, since the example there brings in an innocent third party.

Comment: It's being used to show how important a  principle is. Not because its an identical situation. (After all, if it was an identical situation, we would have our answer.....)

Comment: Preserving a life is an important principle, but at the same time the Torah permits killing a rodef. Would you agree that if someone starts chasing you with a gun yelling 'I'm gonna kill you' he would be a rodef and you'd be permitted to kill him? If yes, this question asks whether someone who points a gun  at you to (ostensibly) rob you, is any different from that case. If it's different, why, and where do we draw the line?

Comment: If someone states they intend to kill, then thats a totally different situation. Then you are defending your life, not just your wallet. If someone states they want your wallet, then on what grounds do you believe that (upon peaceful compliance, which is under your own control and you can unilaterally choose to perform) your life is being sought, or any harm to you personally? And if not, then you aren't defending your life, only your wallet. And that's not good enough to kill them. (A wallet is not worth the life of this man; the Talmud makes clear the HUGE value even of such a life)

Comment: Because you can argue that once the robber pointed the gun at you, you can never be sure of his intentions. You can comply 100% and still be shot, because he doesn't want any witnesses for example. Or he might misinterpret a wrong move you make as threatening and shoot you at any point. So if you have the opportunity to take out the threat and eliminate the guesswork about your life, maybe you should? As long as it's halachically ok. Which is what this question is asking. I wonder if there have been any explicit discussions in halachic sources about this kind of situation.

Comment: I think we interpret the situation differently. Lets try to bridge that.  Suppose the identically situation, with one crucial difference: you know or believe truly, that if you give your money, he will go away, and do nothing more.  Suppose you truly in your heart believed that. Would halacha now allow you to kill him?

Comment: (For reference, my take on _"you can argue that once the robber pointed the gun at you, you can never be sure of his intentions."_ - You can never be sure of anyones intentions, really. A pwrson follows you down some alley, are they also just heading home? So what does halacha say about killing a wrongdoer who has not indicated any intent to kill, based on an unconfirmed **fear** that he **may** go on to commit a murder if he is not pre-emptorily killed at the time he commits a lesser wrong? Does that help? Because the quotes above suggest very strongly what the answer to * that *, will be.)

Comment: One more thing to consider. Suppose the same scenario with one difference. You walk round the corner of an alley, just as a robber pulls out and waves a gun and demands some terrified third party hand over their money.  Are you justified in shooting him in the back before he realises you're there? (Exact same rationale: he may not want witnesses; cant be sure his intentions.)  Or does that breach the clear intent of Sanhedrin, which clearly shows in multiple cases, that killing when any lesser act is possible, is murder in Halacha ?

Comment: You raise valid points, and I think all of these scenarios hinge on what exactly the criteria for considering someone a rodef are. Is it just what you believe in your heart or does the guy has to actually verbally indicate intent to kill? Or maybe physically indicate (like take a shot in your direction)? The answers are not intuitive or straightforward to me. If someone walks into your house and just silently points a gun at you, that sure seems like a  dangerous rodef. Why should the situation change if he then demands money? Why should you trust him?

Comment: So what I think would be useful here are pointers to halachic discussions from commentators, which codify in more detail what "the exact criteria for being a rodef" are.

Comment: I think we may be at an impasse,because the detail and criteria we would need, i think they may not be written. So we probably have to do what anyone would do - search the heart, discuss with others, ask an authority. But most authorities are guided by the spirit and words of the text, so tbere may be headway possible - thats how i have tried to approach it. A fascinating question for sure,once we discard mundane criminal law, and try to ascertain what halachic law would wish of us.

Comment: @cdog1351 - Noting, "permits" in your 1st comment is very far from "encourages". The extent of permission suggested, comes across as pretty much "if there is absolutely no other option as a last resort". Very far indeed from modern law's concept of "I was afraid what else might be in his mind, so I killed him just in case he would kill me". Your way we are **guaranteed** a life is ended. Mine we have a **good chance no life is ended** (most street robbers dont kill if compliant). Sanhedrin seems to suggest "between the lines", that is of great importance.

Comment: Although robbing and fearsome, when we dont have to kill, but do so anyway, that makes us the murderer, for it was not evident a death was going to happen, at all, but we made it so for sure.  I dont think i can say more, one must make up ones mjnd exactly as you say, at what point a person makes of themselves a rodef.

Comment: A possible answer may be found here https://www.etzion.org.il/en/tanakh/torah/sefer-shemot/parashat-mishpatim/law-thief  where it says "The novelty in the law governing a thief who breaks into someone's house is that the homeowner is not certain that the thief he encounters is prepared to kill him. It is impossible to assess the likelihood that the thief will kill the homeowner, and it stands to reason that no two cases are the same.

Comment: Despite this uncertainty, the Torah permits the killing of the thief even in a case in which there is only a small chance that he will kill the homeowner, as long as this is a reasonable possibility. Only when it is clear ("like the sun," as Rashi puts it, following the gemara in Sanhedrin 72a) to the homeowner that the thief will not kill him is the homeowner forbidden to kill the thief."

Comment: Not quite. Read carefully & note the critical words _"in the night"_. It's making the distinction: you may kill the "professional thief", the one who comes "in the night" and "such a person...will presumably... be prepared to kill the homeowner". He started the transgression, and it's on his head.  The other kind of thief however is NOT so presumed. Of them, it continues instead: _"Sometimes, this thief breaks into a house, and he is motivated by desire for money and meat like a professional thief. In contrast, perhaps there is room to be lenient with someone who suffered a local failure..."_

Comment: The paragraph you quoted is talking about whether to sell the thief for slavery. In fact it says, "As for the halakha, the only difference between the two thieves is whether the thief can be sold into slavery, and here too the difference is for technical reasons." In other words, there is no difference in other areas, such as what you're allowed to do when either type of thief breaks into your house.  Nowhere does it say that you may not kill an 'unprofessional thief'. Also that wouldn't make sense, because how could you possibly determine if the guy who broke into your house

Comment: is a professional thief or not. At that moment, you don't have the time nor luxury nor ability to make any determination like that. Which is very similar to when someone comes up to you with a gun in an alley or on the street.